# Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings when trying to make a JPA NamedQuery

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to work out on a query for a solution in JPA. I worked out the SQL Query, which is the following:

```sql
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM equipo_departamento 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM solicitudes
     WHERE codigo = codigo_equipo_departamento
     AND estatus != 'F')
```

Which apparently works, given the output when trying on pgAdmin 4.

So, I tried translating it to make it a JPA NamedQuery, and got this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "EquipoDepartamento.totalActiveItems", query="SELECT COUNT(e) FROM EquipoDepartamento e WHERE NOT EXISTS" +
            "(SELECT s FROM Solicitudes s WHERE e.codigo = s.codigoEquipoDepartamento AND s.estatus != 'F')")})
```

But, the server started throwing the following exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

root cause

javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

root cause

javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean

root cause

javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

root cause

javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean

root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-6076] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons. 
Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[codigo-->equipo_departamento.codigo]] 
Expression: [
Query Key codigo
   Base domain.EquipoDepartamento{DatabaseTable(t0)=DatabaseTable(equipo_departamento)}]
Query: ReportQuery(name="EquipoDepartamento.totalActiveItems" referenceClass=EquipoDepartamento jpql="SELECT COUNT(e) FROM EquipoDepartamento e WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT s FROM Solicitudes s WHERE e.codigo = s.codigoEquipoDepartamento AND s.estatus != 'F')")
```

I'm not sure about what I'm doing wrong here.

Full error log:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Rest Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Rest Servlet threw exception
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6076] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons. 
Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[codigo-->equipo_departamento.codigo]] 
Expression: [
Query Key codigo
   Base domain.EquipoDepartamento{DatabaseTable(t0)=DatabaseTable(equipo_departamento)}]
Query: ReportQuery(name="EquipoDepartamento.totalActiveItems" referenceClass=EquipoDepartamento jpql="SELECT COUNT(e) FROM EquipoDepartamento e WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT s FROM Solicitudes s WHERE e.codigo = s.codigoEquipoDepartamento AND s.estatus != 'F')")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.unsupportedMappingForObjectComparison(QueryException.java:1170)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.buildObjectJoinExpression(DatabaseMapping.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.normalize(CompoundExpression.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.normalize(SQLSelectStatement.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SubSelectExpression.normalizeSubSelect(SubSelectExpression.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionNormalizer.normalizeSubSelects(ExpressionNormalizer.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.normalize(SQLSelectStatement.java:1534)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.buildReportQuerySelectStatement(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.buildReportQuerySelectStatement(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareReportQuerySelectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:1694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepareSelectAllRows(ReportQuery.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepare(ReadAllQuery.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepare(ReportQuery.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:901)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1124)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:522)
    at eis.ReportesDaoImpl.totalActiveItems(ReportesDaoImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor124.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy563.totalActiveItems(Unknown Source)
    at services.ReportesServiceImpl.totalEquiposUniversidad(ReportesServiceImpl.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor124.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy586.totalEquiposUniversidad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:414)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at services.ReportesService$1258095923$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.totalEquiposUniversidad(Unknown Source)
    at services.rest.ReportesServiceRS.reporteTotalesUniversidad(ReportesServiceRS.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor124.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy585.reporteTotalesUniversidad(Unknown Source)
    at services.rest.__EJB31_Generated__ReportesServiceRS__Intf____Bean__.reporteTotalesUniversidad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The models I'm working with are the following:

EquipoDepartamento:

```java
package domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author Scorpion
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "equipo_departamento")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "EquipoDepartamento.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM EquipoDepartamento e"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EquipoDepartamento.findByCodigo", query = "SELECT e FROM EquipoDepartamento e WHERE e.codigo = :codigo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EquipoDepartamento.totalActiveItems", query="SELECT COUNT(e) FROM EquipoDepartamento e WHERE NOT EXISTS" +
                "(SELECT s FROM Solicitudes s WHERE e.codigo = s.codigoEquipoDepartamento AND s.estatus != 'F')")})
@XmlRootElement
public class EquipoDepartamento implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                    generator = "id_equipoDpto")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_equipoDpto", 
                       sequenceName = "equipo_departamento_codigo_seq",
                       allocationSize = 1)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "codigo")
    private Integer codigo;

    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_departamento", referencedColumnName = "codigo")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Departamento codigoDepartamento;

    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_equipo", referencedColumnName = "codigo")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Equipo codigoEquipo;

    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_estado_equipo", referencedColumnName = "codigo")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private EstadoEquipo codigoEstadoEquipo;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "codigoEquipoDepartamento")
    private List<Solicitudes> solicitudesList;

    public EquipoDepartamento() {
    }

    public EquipoDepartamento(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Departamento getCodigoDepartamento() {
        return codigoDepartamento;
    }

    public void setCodigoDepartamento(Departamento codigoDepartamento) {
        this.codigoDepartamento = codigoDepartamento;
    }

    public Equipo getCodigoEquipo() {
        return codigoEquipo;
    }

    public void setCodigoEquipo(Equipo codigoEquipo) {
        this.codigoEquipo = codigoEquipo;
    }

    public EstadoEquipo getCodigoEstadoEquipo() {
        return codigoEstadoEquipo;
    }

    public void setCodigoEstadoEquipo(EstadoEquipo codigoEstadoEquipo) {
        this.codigoEstadoEquipo = codigoEstadoEquipo;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Solicitudes> getSolicitudesList() {
        return solicitudesList;
    }

    public void setSolicitudesList(List<Solicitudes> solicitudesList) {
        this.solicitudesList = solicitudesList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (codigo != null ? codigo.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof EquipoDepartamento)) {
            return false;
        }
        EquipoDepartamento other = (EquipoDepartamento) object;
        if ((this.codigo == null && other.codigo != null) || (this.codigo != null && !this.codigo.equals(other.codigo))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "domain.EquipoDepartamento[ codigo=" + codigo + " ]";
    }

}
```

Solicitudes:

```java
package domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Scorpion
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "solicitudes")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Solicitudes.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Solicitudes s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Solicitudes.findByCodigo", query = "SELECT s FROM Solicitudes s WHERE s.codigo = :codigo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Solicitudes.findByTipoSolicitud", query = "SELECT s FROM Solicitudes s WHERE s.tipoSolicitud = :tipoSolicitud"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Solicitudes.findByFechaInicio", query = "SELECT s FROM Solicitudes s WHERE s.fechaInicio = :fechaInicio"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Solicitudes.findByFechaAtencion", query = "SELECT s FROM Solicitudes s WHERE s.fechaAtencion = :fechaAtencion")})
@XmlRootElement
public class Solicitudes implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                    generator = "id_solicitud")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_solicitud", 
                       sequenceName = "solicitudes_codigo_seq",
                       allocationSize = 1)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "codigo")
    private Integer codigo;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "tipo_solicitud")
    private String tipoSolicitud;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "fecha_inicio")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaInicio;

    @Column(name = "fecha_atencion")
    private Integer fechaAtencion;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "estatus")
    private String estatus;

    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_equipo_departamento", referencedColumnName = "codigo")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private EquipoDepartamento codigoEquipoDepartamento;

    @JoinColumn(name = "nombre_usuario", referencedColumnName = "nombre_usuario")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Usuario nombreUsuario;

    public Solicitudes() {
    }

    public Solicitudes(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Solicitudes(Integer codigo, String tipoSolicitud, Date fechaInicio, String estatus) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.tipoSolicitud = tipoSolicitud;
        this.fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
        this.estatus = estatus;
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getTipoSolicitud() {
        return tipoSolicitud;
    }

    public void setTipoSolicitud(String tipoSolicitud) {
        this.tipoSolicitud = tipoSolicitud;
    }

    public Date getFechaInicio() {
        return fechaInicio;
    }

    public void setFechaInicio(Date fechaInicio) {
        this.fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
    }

    public Integer getFechaAtencion() {
        return fechaAtencion;
    }

    public void setFechaAtencion(Integer fechaAtencion) {
        this.fechaAtencion = fechaAtencion;
    }

    public String getEstatus() {
        return estatus;
    }

    public void setEstatus(String estatus) {
        this.estatus = estatus;
    }

    public EquipoDepartamento getCodigoEquipoDepartamento() {
        return codigoEquipoDepartamento;
    }

    public void setCodigoEquipoDepartamento(EquipoDepartamento codigoEquipoDepartamento) {
        this.codigoEquipoDepartamento = codigoEquipoDepartamento;
    }

    public Usuario getNombreUsuario() {
        return nombreUsuario;
    }

    public void setNombreUsuario(Usuario nombreUsuario) {
        this.nombreUsuario = nombreUsuario;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (codigo != null ? codigo.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Solicitudes)) {
            return false;
        }
        Solicitudes other = (Solicitudes) object;
        if ((this.codigo == null && other.codigo != null) || (this.codigo != null && !this.codigo.equals(other.codigo))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "domain.Solicitudes[ codigo=" + codigo + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem might lie within the definition of your entities. I think, adding the code of those would help to solve the problem.

Comment: `EquipoDepartamento.codigo` is an `Integer`, while `Solicitudes.codigoEquipoDepartamento` is an `EquipoDepartamento`. Why did you think comparing the two was a good idea? You probably meant to use `s.codigoEquipoDepartamento.id` instead

Comment: That was the problem, I was comparing an Integer with an EquipoDepartamento. Fixed now, thank you so much!